# How to update/insert rows and columns of google sheets dynamically in gspread?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a spreadsheet like below and i have an API which will give data as a list by date like below

```
[05/06/2019', 10000, 14003, 140, $576.1786404]
[05/07/2019', 11000, 14003, 140, $576.1786404]
[05/08/2019', 50641, 14067, 357, $578.8120356]
```

[image]

All I have to do is update the data for a date if it already exists **or** insert a new row into the sheet of a new date.

From the above list I have to update data of **05/06/2019** and I have to insert two rows of date **05/07/2019** and **05/08/2019**

I have below code and don't know to do next steps to implement

```
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

worksheet = gc.open("chethan testing").sheet1

cell_list = worksheet.range('A3:E3')
cell_values = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i, val in enumerate(cell_values):
    cell_list[i].value = val 

 worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

Can somebody guide me on how to proceed with next steps.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. In your Spreadsheet, is the date of the column "A" put as the date object? If you cannot check it, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? 2. About ``insert a new row into the sheet of a new date``, do you want to put the value for other sheet? If you use other sheet, can you provide the information?

Comment: @Tanaike 1)the date column is not an object, it is just a string, in some cases date columns will not come in client sheets 2)we will get the complete url of the sheet with id of worksheet that needs to be update or insert

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the above requirement i did like below to get solved.

```
my_list = [['2018-11-10', '1000000000', '14003', '140', '576.1786404'], ['2018-11-11', '506541', '14067', '357', '578.8120356'], ['2018-11-12', '423175', '15250', '330', '627.4887'], ['2018-11-13', '274503', '11337', '240', '466.4812716'], ['2018-11-14', '285468', '11521', '194', '474.0522828']]

worksheet.values_update(
    'Sheet1!A3',
    params={
        'valueInputOption': 'RAW'
    },
    body={
        'values':my_list
    }
)
```

This will update the existing values and add the other values to new rows.

More you can find here https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update